# What do straight lines in a phase space diagram depict?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space

This question surfaced up in my mid terms today .

Comment: I think phase space doesn't usually have a metric, just a symplectic structure. Do you have something more specific in mind?

Comment: What did you write in the mid term to that question, i.e. what do you think the solution to that is?

Comment: What do you think they depict?

Comment: I wrote that they represent no change in the quantity being measured.

Comment: Yeah something doesn't  change if it's for example an orizontal line, what about an oblique line? Think about a position - velocity diagram

Comment: Is this in the context of classical mechanics or statistical physics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phase space is used for simplifying and understanding some physical concepts/mathematical analysis. For example in phase space representing SHM or EM Wave diffraction/superposition, the length of the straight line represents the amplitude and the angle with the axis represents the phase or the initial phase of the system.

So there is a homework for you to figure out what is phase and what actually is the phasor. I hope this will guide you in right direction, as I can't give definite answers on this forum.

For more information please go through following.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_space

Answer (score 0):

The *rectification theorem* says that away from singular points, the dynamics of a point in a small patch is a straight line. The patch can sometimes be enlarged by stitching several patches together, and when this works out in the whole phase space M, the dynamical system is *integrable*. The rectification theorem secures the local existence and uniqueness of solutions of ODEs.

Research action-angle variables and integrability of ODEs.